# Select the most common item for each category

Tags: sql, sqlite

Each row in my table belongs to some *category*, has some *value* and other data.

I would like to select each *category* with the most common *value* for it (doesn't matter which one if there are multiple), ordered by *category*.

```py
some_table:             expected result:
+--------+-----+---     +--------+-----+
|category|value|...     |category|value|
+--------+-----+---     +--------+-----+
|   1    |  a  |        |   1    |  a  |
|   1    |  a  |        |   2    |  b  |
|   1    |  b  |        |   3    |  a  # or b
|   2    |  a  |        +--------+-----+
|   2    |  b  |
|   2    |  c  |
|   2    |  b  |
|   3    |  a  |
|   3    |  a  |
|   3    |  b  |
|   3    |  b  |
+--------+-----+---
```

I have a solution (posting it as an answer) but it seems suboptimal to me. So I'm looking for better solutions.

My table will have up to 10000 rows (possibly, but not likely, beyond that).

I'm planning to use SQLite but I'm not tied to it, so I may reconsider if SQLite can't do this with reasonable performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select distinct category,
       (select value
        from some_table t2
        where t2.category = t.category
        group by value
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as mode_value
from some_table t;
```

The name for the most common value is "mode" in statistics.

And, if you had a `categories` table, this would be written as:

```
select category,
       (select value
        from some_table t2
        where t2.category = c.category
        group by value
        order by count(*) desc
        limit 1
       ) as mode_value
from categories c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, but I think it's slow...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `category` AS `the_category`, `value`
FROM `some_table`
WHERE `value`=(
    SELECT `value`
    FROM `some_table`
    WHERE `category`=`the_category`
    GROUP BY `value`
    ORDER BY COUNT(`value`) DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY `category`;
```

You can replace a part of this with `` WHERE `id`=(  SELECT `id` `` if the table has a unique/primary key column, then the `LIMIT 1` is not needed.

Comment: Can that subquery be possibly a join? will that increase speed?

Comment: @Rahul I don't know. I'm a newbie to this.

Answer (score -1):

```
select category, value, count(*) value_count 
from some_table t
group by category, value
order by category, value_count DESC;
```

returns us amout of each value in each category

```
select category, value
from (
    select category, value, count(*) value_count 
    from some_table t
    group by category, value) sub
group by category
```

actually we need the first value because it's sorted.

I am not sure sqlite leaves the first one and can't test but IMHO it should work

Comment: The values in the result are not the most common ones.